# Reasons & Consequences of putting a Date in Elastic Index Name

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I am looking at sending my App logs to Elastic *(6.x)* via FileBeat and Logstash. As mentioned in [Configure the Logstash output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/logstash-output.html) and recommended elsewhere, it seems that I need add the Date to the Index name. The reason for doing so was that when the time came to delete old data, it was easier to delete an entire Index by date, rather than individual documents. Is this true?

If I should be following this recommendation of adding the Date to the Index Name, I’m curious what additional things I need to do to ensure seamless querying? By this I mean querying esp. in Kibana, for e.g. over the past day which would need to look at today’s index as well as yesterday’s index.

Speaking of querying in Kibana, is there a way of simply working with the base index name without the date stamp i.e. setting it up so that I do not see or have to deal with the date named indexes?

---

**Edit:** **Kamal** raised a good point that I have not provided any information about my cluster and my needs. The following is what I'm working with:

> What is your daily data creation/expected count

I'm not sure. I don't expect anything more than a GB of data day, and no more than a couple of 100K documents a day. Since these are logs, I don't expect any updates to the documents once they are created.

> Growth rate of the data in the future (1 year - 5 years)

At the moment, I don't see the growth rate to cross a GB a day.

> How many teams are using the same cluster apart from yours if there is
>   any

The cluster would be used (actually queried) by just my team. We are about 5 right now, but I don't see more than 10 users (and that's not concurrent, just over a day or month)

> Usage patterns, type of queries used etc.

I'm not sure, but there certainly would not be updates to the data other than deletions

> Hardware details

I've not worked this out with management. For most part I expect 3 nodes. Also this is not critical i.e. if we lose all of our logs for some reason, I would not lose sleep over it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you need to take a step back and understand do you really need `multiple index` or `single one`(*where you need to filter documents while querying using a date field for a particular date*).

Some of questions you must have before you take on such decision

- What is your daily data creation/expected count
- Growth rate of the data in the future (1 year - 5 years)
- How many teams are using the same cluster apart from yours if there is any
- Usage patterns, type of queries used etc.
- Hardware details

**Advantages**

In a way, having multiple indexes(*with date field as its index name*) would be more beneficial.

- You can delete the old indexes without affecting new ones.
- In case if you have to change the mapping, you can do so with the new index without affecting the old ones. Comparatively less overhead while for single index, you have to reindex all the documents which would take lot more time if size is pretty huge. And if this keeps happening every now and then, you would need to come up with solution where you have to execute such operations at the times of minimal usages. That means, it can harm productivity.
- searching using multiple indexes still is convenient.
- not really sure but its easier for scaling using multiple indexes.

**Disadvantages are:**

- Additional shards are created for each and every index that can waste some storage space.
- Overhead to maintain multiple indexes by monitoring/operations team.
- At times can lead to over-creation of indexes.
- No mapping changes and less documents insertion(in 100s or few 100s), it'd be better to use single index.

The only way and the only correct way to figure out what's best is to have a cluster that closely resembles the production one with data too resembling to production, try various configurations and see which solution fits best.

> Speaking of querying in Kibana, is there a way of simply working with
>   the base index name without the date stamp i.e. setting it up so that
>   I do not see or have to deal with the date named indexes?

Yes there is. If you have indexes with names like logs-0001, logs-0002, you can use `logs-*` as indexname when you query.

Comment: Thank you *Kamal*. I like where you are going esp. that this choice is not set in stone. I'm wondering if you could throw light on how bad would it be to delete documents for a single day using the Delete API in a single index, vs deleting an entire Index. I could do this over the night when there were less users on the cluster? Would the cluster be unable to add logs when this happens, or it would just do so with a delay? Would the space be eventually recovered i.e. after a few days, not immediately? Or perhaps I could start a separate SO Question on this topic.

Comment: Of course `deleting index` is more efficient than deletion using `delete by query`, as the latter happens by taking snapshot of entire index &  if any document gets changed in the meanwhile, ya'll get version conflict. Basically lot more checks, operations gets executed in delete by query as opposed to deletion of index and I think even more so in making the space available. As for how deletion of documents works under the hood, refer to this blog https://www.elastic.co/blog/lucenes-handling-of-deleted-documents.

Comment: Thank you **Kamal**. I liked your link to the Blog, esp. the section on **How Do Deleted Documents Affect Search Performance?** which seems to indicate that query performance reduces at the most 50% and is less for more costly queries. I'm leaning towards `delete by query`, but I would test it with actual data before making a determination.

Answer (score 2):

Including date in an index name is a very common use case implemened by many Elasticsearch users. It helps with archiving/ purging old indices as you mentioned. You dont need to do anything additionally to be able to query. Setup your index basename as an index pattern for your indices for ex. logstash-* and you can query on that particular index pattern in Kibana.

Comment: Thank you *ben5556*. I'm wondering if I need to set up Index Aliases: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html in Elastic to use this. I'm also wondering if there is a way to work without the wildcard character * in the index name in Kibana?

Comment: No, you dont need aliases. Without using an index pattern with a wildcard character how are you going to view your data or create visualizations ?

Comment: Thank you **ben5556** I was hoping for an alternative to using the wildcard character in Kibana. Its bad that I cannot select two answers, but you and **Kamal** did answer different parts of the question.  Thank you again.